# Using an Image Carousel in React, strange rendering issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm working on my portfolio site and I was following a guide to making an image carousel for my 'about' section, was planning on putting 3 photos in the carousel to cycle through. The functionality is mostly there, however I've run into a strange issue that I can't figure out how to solve.

The way this is set up in my about section is as such:

**components/About/index.js**

```
            <Carousel>
                <CarouselItem>Item 1</CarouselItem>
                <CarouselItem>Item 2</CarouselItem>
                <CarouselItem>Item 3</CarouselItem>
            </Carousel>
```

The way this is supposed to work is that each CarouselItem is going to be the image that is cycled through. However, while testing, I have come upon the issue that there are 3 slides created, however, slide 1 inputs each carousel item stacked on top of one another, and the other 2 slides to render, but they are blank. This is confusing for a number of reasons, here is an image of what I see on the page.   [![Improper rendering][1]][1]

If anyone can take a look at the code here, I would appreciate it. I'm not sure what I would need to alter to fix this, but I would be happy to attach any extra code to any replies if someone is kind enough to help. Fairly new to React, but I believe the issue may be caused by nesting the Carousel components within the 'About' component. Below is the Carousel.js, which includes both the Carousel and CarouselItem components, the rendering in the 'About' section, as well as the rendering in the App.js where it is all imported. In writing this post, I have realized the naming convention is a bit off which may possibly cause an issue somewhere, though I think that is doubtful.

**components/Carousel/Carousel.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export const CarouselItem = ({ children, width }) => {
    return (
        <div className='carousel-item' style={{ width: width }}>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
};

const Carousel = ({ children }) => {

    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
    const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);

    const updateIndex = (newIndex) => {
        if (newIndex < 0) {
            newIndex = React.Children.count(children) - 1;
        } else if (newIndex >= React.Children.count(children)) {
            newIndex = 0;
        }


        setActiveIndex(newIndex);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (!paused) {
                updateIndex(activeIndex + 1);
            }
        }, 2000);

        return () => {
            if (interval) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        };
    });


    return (
        <div 
          className='carousel'
          onMouseEnter={() => setPaused(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setPaused(false)}>
            <div className='inner' style={{ transform: `translateX(-${activeIndex * 100}%)` }}>
                {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
                    return React.cloneElement(child, { width: '100%' });
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Carousel;
```

**components/About/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Carousel, { CarouselItem } from '../Carousel/Carousel';
import './style.css';

function About() {

    return (
        <div className='about'>
            <h2>About Me</h2>
            <Carousel>
                <CarouselItem>Item 1</CarouselItem>
                <CarouselItem>Item 2</CarouselItem>
                <CarouselItem>Item 3</CarouselItem>
            </Carousel>
            <p className='lh-base'>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default About;
```

**App.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navigation from './components/Navbar';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import About from './components/About';
import Portfolio from './components/Portfolio';
import Resume from './components/Resume';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import 'react-bootstrap';


const App = () => {

  const [currentDisplay, setCurrentDisplay] = useState('About');

  const showDisplay = () => {
    switch (currentDisplay) {
      case 'About':
        return <About />;
      case 'Portfolio':
        return <Portfolio />;
      case 'Contact':
        return <Contact />;
      case 'Resume':
        return <Resume />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='App' style={{backgroundColor: '#E9CE7A'}}>
      <Navigation
        currentDisplay={currentDisplay}
        setCurrentDisplay={setCurrentDisplay}
      />
      <main>
        {showDisplay(currentDisplay)}
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Pre-emptive thank you to anyone who takes a look and attempts to help, this could be an obvious issue that I'm missing as I'm quite new to React.

Adding CSS at request of commenter:

**components/Carousel/style.css**

```
.carousel {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.carousel-item {
    display: infline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**components/About/style.css**

```
.about {
    margin: 3rem;
    background-color: #E9CE7A;
}

.about h2{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 3rem !important;
}

.about img {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin-bottom: 3rem !important;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.about p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

FIX EDIT: Commenter notified me of a typo in my CSS - leaving up in case it helps anyone else. Thank you, SamiElk!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/270uH.png

Comment: Could you add the css?

Comment: Added the style.css for both the Carousel and About components to the bottom of the post!

Comment: You made a typo it is `inline-flex;` instead of `infline-flex;`

Comment: I cannot believe how simple of a fix that was -- thank you for saving me a headache! Upon fixing, it worked! Thank you so much!